# Github: Use ssh key to use in only one repository or organization

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

It is possible to create an SSH Key who only have access to one repository or one organization and all the other ones will be rejected?

For example, you have access to this 4 repositories:

```
git@github.com:MyUser/repo-u1.git
git@github.com:MyUser/repo-u2.git
git@github.com:OrgRepo/repo-o1.git
git@github.com:OrgRepo/repo-o2.git
```

**First case:**

You create an ssh-key who only have access to `OrgRepo`. So, if the key is stolen and hacked the hacker only can have access to `OrgRepo/repo-o1.git` and `OrgRepo/repo-o2.git` but if he tries to clone the `MyUser/repo-u1.git` or `MyUser/repo-u1.git` will be rejected.

**Second case:**

You create an ssh-key who only have access to `MyUser/repo-u2.git`. So, if the key is stolen and hacked the hacker only can have access `MyUser/repo-u2.git` but will be rejected for the other 3 repositories.

Comment: Discussion on GitHub community forums (unfortunately hasn't gotten much attention): https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/4699

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GitHub doesn't provide exactly what you want, but it does provide some similar functionality.

First, if your organization is using SAML single sign-on, then an SSH key must be explicitly enabled for SSO before it can access the repositories for that organization. Similarly, personal access tokens must be enabled for SSO as well. There is no functionality for the reverse, preventing organization-enabled credentials from accessing personal resources.

Second, if you have an automated system, such as a CI server, that only needs to access one repository, you can create an SSH deploy key to access only that repository. This is not a good tool for individuals to use because it lacks traceability, but it is a good tool for automated systems.

Beyond that, no, GitHub doesn't provide what you're looking for.

Comment: How can I enable SSO for my key? I don't seem to have an alternative for that.

Comment: If you're part of an organization that uses SAML SSO, then the documentation is here: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/authorizing-an-ssh-key-for-use-with-saml-single-sign-on

Answer (score 5):

For the second case, look into [deploy keys](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys) where you can limit SSH key access on a per-repo basis.